# How to rename all files in a directory in linux with string substitution?

Tags: linux, bash, slackware

i want to rename multiple files in my linux system directory....

my file names are as:

```
Lec 1 - xxx.webm
Lec 2 - xxx.webm
Lec 3 - xxx.webm
Lec 4 - xxx.webm
```

and the list goes on...

here xxx could be any list of characters(not consistent)....

i would like to rename every file in here like:

```
mv Lec 1 - xxx.webm Lec 1.webm
mv Lec 2 - xxx.webm Lec 2.webm
mv Lec 3 - xxx.webm Lec 3.webm
```

and so on....

for in loop could do but how to do the substitution?

*strip all characters after the number should be my renamed file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop should do the job:

```
for f in *.webm; do
   mv "$f" "${f/ -*/}.webm"
done
```

Comment: the file name changed to `Lec n - webm.webm`

Comment: No `${f/ -*/}` will strip everything after `" -"` in original string and then `.webm` will be added back.

Comment: now all my files have been renamed to `Lec n.webm.webm`
can you help me rename it back to `Lec n.webm` only?

i tried this link but i get error

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-single-command-or-script-in-unix

Comment: Yes you can use this loop: `for f in *.webm.webm; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.webm}"; done` to fix those filenames

Comment: i try this and i get error
`for file in $(find . -name "*webm")
do
    mv "$file" "${file/.webm/ }"
done`


`
mv: cannot stat '7.webm.webm': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat './Lec': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '8.webm.webm': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat './Lec': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '9.webm.webm': No such file or directory
`

Comment: But I didn't give you any `find` command to start with. Besides `"${file/.webm/ }"` is just wrong. If you want to use find then use: **`find . -name '*.webm.webm' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.webm}"' - {} \;`**

Comment: thanks its resolved!

may i know why this is wrong?

`"${file/.webm/ }"`

Comment: `"${file/.webm/ }"` will convert `'a.webm.webm'` into `'a .webm'`

Answer (score 2):

`${string%substring}`: deletes shortest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`.

```
for i in *.webm; do mv $i ${i%xxx}; done
```

Or check out:

`${string%%substring}`: deletes longest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `util-linux-ng` installed:

```
find . -name "Lec*.webm" | xargs rename s/ -*//
```

or:

```
for file in $(find . -name "Lec*.webm")
do 
  echo mv "$file" "`echo $file | sed s/ -*$//`"
done
```